# Create autolayout for detailed view controller when navigation bar is visible

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, uikit

I don't embed my detailed view controller in a `UINavigationController`. This is how my storyboard looks:

[image]

So this all looks good on an iPad (or iPhone6+):

[image]

But when on iPhone <= 6 we get a navigation bar so we can go back again:

[image]

I wanted to add a table and I set the constraints so the table takes the entire size of my view. On iPhone <= 6 **the first rows of the table is being shown under the navigation bar**. Is it possible to fix this in the interface builder? Thanks.

**EDIT**:
Here's an image of my constraints from the interface builder:

[image]

- Trailing and leading spaces, to create same width as superview
- Bottom space to toolbar, to avoid colliding into it
- Top space to superview, to start from the top in the superview

So it's the top space that is not set from the navigation bar when that is displayed for iPhone <= 6.

Comment: can you please show that how you have applied constraints to tableview by posting image and also show how you have set frame of tableview's frame from Interface builder?

Comment: yup, I added it now with a summary

Answer (score 0):

Please change top space from 0 pixels to 64 pixels. Also, change the top constraint from superview to 64. (This is because the status bar is having height of 20 pixels and navigation bar is having height of 44 pixels. So, total is 64 pixels you have to set.)

Comment: Also? Isn't that doing the same thing? Wouldn't that be weird when navigationbar is not showing?

Comment: I see you edited this answer, but still I want the table to start from the top when I have no navigation bar. Sometimes it's there, sometimes not.

Comment: You have to hide navigation bar and change top constraint's constant programatically.